# How to check what properties exist in a class after a __call method is used to load them?

Tags: php, pdo

PDO has a predefined fetch modes that can be passed into the `fetch` and `fetchAll` methods. I am mainly concentrating on `FETCH_CLASS` in my issue.

In order to load the properties and values into my class I created a trait to allow for magic methods `__set`.

```
trait Entity {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->_attributes = func_get_args();
  }

  public function __set($prop, $value) {
    if (in_array($prop, $this->_attributes))
        $this->$prop = $value;
  }
}
```

This then can be easily used across the application by using the trait in a class.

```
class UserModel {
    use Entity;

    public function save() {

    }
}
```

The issue I am having now is implementing the magic method `__get` to now be able to save the data based off the class properties and values. In order to load data into the `UserModel`, I can just create a PDO instance and query like so:

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT user_id, email, username, hash FROM app_users WHERE user_id = 1');
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'UserModel');
```

I tried to generate the additional `__get` method in my trait like so:

```
public function __get($prop) {
    if(isset($this->$prop)) return $this->$prop;
}
```

But I am now stuck with how to use the instance to update the row when the PDO instance is outside of its scope. I tried to implement a singleton trait for the PDO like so:

```
trait Singleton
{
  private static $instance;

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if(self::$instance) return self::$instance;
    self::$instance = new self();
    return self::$instance;
  }  

  protected function __construct() {}
  private function __clone() {}
}
```

And a really quick extension of the PDO for basic implementation for now.

```
class PDOWrapper extends PDO
{
  use Singleton;

  protected function __construct()
  {
    parent::_construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4', array(
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ));
  }

  public function query($sql)
  {
    return parent::prepare($sql);
  }
}
```

Which then changes my whole approach to fetching the row into the class to look something like this:

```
$stmt = PDOWrapper::getInstance()->query('SELECT user_id, email, username, hash FROM app_users WHERE user_id = 1');
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'UserModel');
```

Now inside my `save()` method, I have access to the same PDO instance using `PDOWrapper::getInstance()`. The issue I have is that you need to know **what** properties where loaded from the SQL query to get the necessary values.

For example, prior, I loaded the `email`, `user_id` and `username` columns into the class. I want to update the password for that user. This property does **not** exist in the first fetch. How can I check what properties exist in the class?

```
// Won't work
public function save() {
    $stmt = PDOWrapper::getInstance()->query('UPDATE app_users SET hash = ? WHERE user_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($this->__get('hash'), $this->__get('user_id')));
}
```

I need a solution that is dynamic to the properties set, for example which should probably all be a batch update:

```
// Sudo code
PDOWrapper::getInstance()->beginTransaction(); // Will need to be added
foreach($this->props as $prop)
    PDOWrapper::getInstance()->query('UPDATE table SET prop = value where user_id = value')->execute(array($this->$prop, $this->user_id));
```

Comment: As a general sentiment, I would say this is the point where your too quick and too dirty homebrewed ORM is going to break no matter how much chewing gum and duct tape is going to be used.

Comment: After doing a `var_dump( array_keys( (array)  $this ) )` I cannot see any properties that have been set. I used [an online PHP tester](https://3v4l.org/bG2pr) to test this, see the link for demo, and it doesn't actually store the arguments. Perhaps this is why I am stuck, any idea to how to correct this? @YourCommonSense

Comment: As a slightly relevant note, why would you fetch only a limited subset of properties when instantiating your model class? Wouldn't it solve your problem if you would just select all properties?

Comment: Well, I wouldn’t need to pull a users hash, for example, for someone the user is searching for. Also, sometimes I’ll INNER JOIN tables based on what information I need at that given time. So it would solve my issue in theory but I’d be pointlessly loading tonnes of data @YourCommonSense